# DynamoDB PowerShell: can't create local table in selected region

Tags: node.js, powershell, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm trying to create a table in a local instance of DynamoDB using PowerShell cmdlets. In VS AWS Explorer I created a DDB instance and bound it to port:10000. Right after that, the new DB was created where name is KEYID_us-east-1.db

In the PS script, I'm setting up the AWS context and the table to create it in eu-central-1 region. Despite this, the new table is created in us-east-1 db, so the PS cmdlet ignored my region settings and used default one.

In the mean time, when I specify a different region in NodeJS, but the same endpoint that I use in PS script, after accessing the db, the new DB appears with region that I specified.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the "Notes" section on the below link. Looks like the local dynamodb instance use the region to create the database file. However, the local instance is not using the region effectively in the same way as AWS remote dynamodb instance.

"Bullet Point : 2 - The values that you supply for the AWS access key and the Region are only used to name the database file."

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development/